# JavaFX Scene Builder Issues

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have quite an issue when trying to work with scrollpane in Scene Builder.

I have tried just about anything, including google searching.

Scene Builder does not allow me to scroll down the scrollpane, when editing the fxml document.

This means that I can't put in the elements I want, in the layout that I want, since I am working on a long scrollable scene.

Any fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Yes: adjust the `hvalue`/`vvalue` property or better use 2 different fxml: One for the scrollpane content and one containing the `TabPane` + `ScrollPane` and include use include to add the content fxml to the scrollpane...

Comment: Thanks a lot @fabian